# How to retrieve NSUserDefault value in upgraded app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsfilemanager

I am making video app. In that im creating multiple video path using

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Video%@.mov",[NSDate date]];

NSString *videoPath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:string];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
```

and exporting using AVAssetExportSession. After that, I am adding each exporter url into NSUserDefault

`

```
NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"video"] mutableCopy];

NSData *personEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:outputURL];

[archiveArray addObject:personEncodedObject];

NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userData setObject:archiveArray forKey:@"video"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Now, problem is when I release new version of my app, I cant access previously stored video url in NSUserdefault.**

Answer (score 1):

NSUserdefault are maintain by iOS, you have no need to worry about in updating your app version,

If you have save some data in dafaults it will remains same in your updated version of app.

Comment: when I upgraded my app, i cant load the videos which are captured using previous app version?

Comment: That is not possible you are missing something, show your code for storing url in defaults.

Comment: its there in my question.

Comment: @venky: you are asking for url before storing it in defaults?

Comment: show your actual code, i guess this is edited, please show us correct code so we can help you.